# Display patterns using for loops c++

Tags: c++

Hi guys I'm learning C++ language. 
how to display this patterns using for loops?
where the given numbers are from the user input.

[image: example]

Comment: Any code you have written?

Comment: Store each line of that output in a `string`, then loop through these `string`s in a for-loop. Technically, it meets your requirement of using for-loops.

Comment: The third pattern looks strange...

Answer (score 0):

**For first pattern, I generated a code:**

```
void firstpattern(int width)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<width;i++)
        printf("+-------");
    printf("+\n");
    for(i=0;i<width;i++)
        printf("|\t");
    printf("|\n");
    for(i=0;i<width;i++)
        printf("|\t");
    printf("|\n");
    for(i=0;i<width;i++)
        printf("+-------");
    printf("+\n");
}
```

From main function, I am calling this method
    *`firstpattern(width);`*
Then think yourself from this code and and generate the next two pattern with your thinking.